# Conversion failed : converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following function which returns the following result set when this string is called.

```
SELECT item 
FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K('985B773F-5E36-47D4-9E84-E0CE35B34337,32237666-86F3-41FD-BCDE-794571CDAEA2',',')
```

Result set:

```
item
------------------------------------
985B773F-5E36-47D4-9E84-E0CE35B34337    
32237666-86F3-41FD-BCDE-794571CDAEA2
```

Now the purpose of this function is to get the two or more IDs cause I will be passing multiple IDs from my C# program to one variable in my stored procedure.

**Problem**

The problem seems to be simple enough but I am not sure as to why it's occurring.

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[usp_printMulitTest]
    @multiApplicationId_FK uniqueidentifier = '',
    @pDelimiter CHAR(1) = NULL
AS  
    ;WITH image_CTE(imgBinary, imgCode, appID) AS
    (
        SELECT 
            [image], imageCode_FK, app
        FROM   
            [dbo].Images  
        WHERE 
            CAST('985B773F-5E36-47D4-9E84-E0CE35B34337,32237666-86F3-41FD-BCDE-794571CDAEA2' AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER) 
                IN ((SELECT item 
                     FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(CAST('985B773F-5E36-47D4-9E84-E0CE35B34337,32237666-86F3-41FD-BCDE-794571CDAEA2' AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER),',')))
     )
     SELECT * 
     FROM image_CTE
```

This stored procedure works fine when I hard code the variables.

However, when I convert it to this

```
WHERE CAST(app AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER) 
   IN((SELECT item FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(CAST(@multiApplicationId_FK AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER),','  )))
```

to get the results for the app IDs that I pass in, I get an error

> Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier

While looking for solutions two that were pointed out is the incorrect formation of the unique identifier and not using cast, however I checked the numbers and used a cast/convert and there has been no change.

Grateful for assistance in this.

Comment: You don't need CAST(@multiApplicationId_FK AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER). This is assuming your function expects comma separated values as string. Reason your hardcoded value runs fine is because `CAST('985B773F-5E36-47D4-9E84-E0CE35B34337,32237666-86F3-41FD-BCDE-794571CDAEA2' AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)`  will return first uniqueidentifier of the two. PLease tell us what is the value of @multiApplicationId_FK variable

Comment: `CAST('985B773F-5E36-47D4-9E84-E0CE35B34337,32237666-86F3-41FD-BCDE-794571CDAEA2' AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)` is not correct usage of CAST if you want to cast both values as `uniqueidentifier`. Which I think is what you want to do.

Comment: Also looks like @multiApplicationId_FK should be `varchar` instead of `uniqueidentifier` if you wanna pass multiple comma separated values

Comment: @AB_87 Yes, I did that , but to get it to work i casted multiApplicationId_FK  as a varchar.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. That variable should be declared as varchar. Cast is not required. Also, 'CAST('985B773F-5E36-47D4-9E84-E0CE35B34337,32237666-86F3-41FD-BCDE-794571CDAEA2' AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER) ' is incorrect use.

Comment: Please share you table structure for Image table.